# Python Dictionary- single key, multi value pair

Tags: python

```
Dict= [('or', []), ('and', [5, 12]), ('with', [9])]
```

This is a single key, multi value pair.

I want to assign `5` and `12` to `'and'` separately.

Desired output

```
[('or', []), ('and', [5]), ('and',[12]), ('with', [9])]
```

How to proceed.. ?
And, I want to make this general like length can be more than 2 also.

Comment: there is no dictionary here. Just tuples. And what did you try?

Comment: thats not a dict, its a list of tuples. You can split this in a for loop.

Comment: Also do you insist in the single-item lists?

Comment: That makes no sense. why would you have a tuple in a tuple. You could use a dict.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
d= [('or', []), ('and', [5, 12]), ('with', [9])]
new_d = [g for h in [[i] if len(i[-1]) < 2 else [(i[0], c) for c in i[-1]] for i in d] for g in h]
```

Output:

```
[('or', []), ('and', 5), ('and', 12), ('with', [9])]
```

Comment: @Ev.Kounis how is this unreadable? The use of the ternary operator is quite strait-forward and the nested lists are not too convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a *good-ol* for loop here. A list-comprehension would be so convoluted that would end up being incomprehensible I am afraid.

```
data = [('or', []), ('and', [5, 12]), ('with', [9])]

res = []
for k, v in data:
    if len(v)>1:
        for r in v:
            res.append((k, [r]))
    else:
        res.append((k, v))
print(res)
```

which produces:

```
[('or', []), ('and', [5]), ('and', [12]), ('with', [9])]
```

Comment: Agreed. One-liner solutions for the sake of having a one-liner solution are rarely a good idea.

Comment: @SethMMorton it's not like: `[(a, el) for a, b in Dict for el in b or [b]]` is massively unreadable though... Don't think the listing might be quite right, but fairly easily tweakable...

Comment: @JonClements This is indeed very readable and elegant.. The result it produces is not exactly the one OP wants but still hats off.

Comment: @JonClements That is very readable.  My comment was not intended to be read as "all one-liners are bad and unreadable", it was intended to be read as "people often ask for/give one-liner solutions when that is probably not the best solution."  I like a good one-liner as much as the next programmer, but like hot sauce it is best in moderation.

Answer (score 0):

Some more fun adding to the given answers: 
If you don't care about the order, you can make the list comprehension like so:

```
transf_dict = [(x[0],y) for x in Dict for y in x[1]] + [(x[0],[])  for x in Dict if not x[1]]
```

You could also transform your dict to an actual dictionary

```
newdict = dict(Dict)
```

which makes, I think, stuff a lot more readable. For example:

```
transf_dict = []
for key,item in newdict.items():
    if not item:
        transf_dict.append((key,[]))
    else:
        transf_dict.extend([(key,[x]) for x in item])
```

would give your desired output, but all at the cost of ordering. If you're willing to change the format a little, try:

```
transf_dict = [(x, lst) for x, y in Dict for lst in (y if y else [[]])]
```